# transaction.atomic celery task

Tags: django, celery, django-orm

I have transaction.atomic celery task:

```
@app.task(
    name="create_order",
    bind=True,
    ignore_results=True,
)
@transaction.atomic
def create_order(self: Task) -> None:
    
    try:
        data = MyModel.objects.select(...)
        # Some actions that may take long time and only use DB for SELECT queries 
        make_order(data, ...)
    except SomeException as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=5)
    else:
        data.status = DONE
        data.save()
```

`@transaction.atomic` decorator creates new connection with DB and holds it before any exception or `COMMIT` statement. But what if task raises `self.retry`? Connection will be closed and when the task retries django will open a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, [`transaction.atomic` does not open a new connection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_modules/django/db/transaction/#atomic), it grabs an existing connection out of the `django.db.connections` collection, and these connections are typically instantiated at startup.  The connections stay live and are reused across the app.  Typically, all of the connections do a `ping` before executing a query to make sure the connection is usable (otherwise a new connection will be established).  Exiting the code block of the task will not close the connection, and depending on your connection settings, the same process will happen when the process is retried (`transaction.atomic` will grab the connection out of the `connections` collection and then the execution of the query will do the connectivity check).